# get the child ul id

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

in my tree structure when a sibling is added
(ul)
(li)
(div)
span node name span
(/div)
(/li)
............... this strucutre goes on at one level when i add a child than the strucutre becomes like this

```
  (ul)
     (li)
       (div)
          span node name span(selected)

        (ul id="ul1")
        (li)
           (div)
              (span) child node name(/span)
           (/div)

        (/li)

     (/div)
```

....................... it goes on untill there is one more level added.
the thing is that i want to get the id of child ul when the parent span is selected.
get ul1 as result

Answer (score 0):

If the UL is a descendant of the span (which is how I understand this problem), you can do this:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    alert($(this).find("ul").attr("id"));
});
```

If the UL is always the very next sibling, you can use `.next`:

```
$(this).next("ul").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select it you can grab it, for example:

```
$("span").click(function() {
  var ulID = $(this).siblings("ul").attr("id");
});
```

In your case it *appears* to be a sibling, so [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

for my it looks like you want to find the first `ul` as a child of a parent `ul`.

So try this:

```
$( 'ul' ).click( function() {
  console.debug( $(this).find('ul').attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: `.attr("attribute")` already gets the attribute of the first element in the set, no need to add a step here :)